# custom validator not working with textbox that has calendar extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes with calendar extendars. One labeled start date and the other end date. If a user enters a start date then they must enter an end date. My custom validator is not firing.

Aspx:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EndDateTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="DateValidationGroup">hiiiiiiii</asp:CustomValidator>
```

C#

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (StartDateTextBox.Text !="" & EndDateTextBox.Text =="")
        {
            args.IsValid = false;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Do you have any Javascript on the page also?  The validation wouldn't fire in the C# back-end if you have a javascript error on the page.  That's the only thing I can think of right now.  Nothing is jumping out at me otherwise.  Also, I'm assuming you have the same validation group set on a button or some control that will fire all your validations, right?

Comment: Yes. Same validation group on Button. There is no Java. It works with a required field validator but not custom. Not sure why.